# ANSI Colors when using Systemd Service

Tags: systemd, ansi-term

I have setup a server for [SSHTron](http://sshtron.zachlatta.com), a game which can be played by ssh-ing into a `sshtron` server.
Color matters a lot in this game.

I can run the ssh server by running the executable I got: `./sshtron-server`

And it worked fine, the users were able to play the game in color mode.

`ssh sshtron.myserver.com`

I wanted to make a service so that it starts automatically if my system restarts.

But when I did, and the users were seeing the game without colors.

The following is my `sshtron.service` file:

```
[Unit]
Description=SSHTron

[Service]
Type=simple
WorkingDirectory=/home/pi/go/src/zachlatta/sshtron
ExecStart=/home/pi/go/src/zachlatta/sshtron/sshtron-server

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

**UPDATED:**

I tried to wrap the server in a *Docker* container as well, but the result is same, no colors. :(

**UPDATED:**

Looks like we need to find a way to allocate a pseudo-tty and run `sshtron` over it, using `systemd`.

Comment: Can you set the ``TERM`` environment variable when it runs as a service?

Comment: I looked into this and filed a related "wish" request with the project here: https://github.com/zachlatta/sshtron/issues/19

Comment: Since Docker was also option for me, I managed to get it working under a container by attaching it to a tty. https://github.com/zachlatta/sshtron/pull/20